# How to make modal/pop-up have a several tabs in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create an app using Ionic which have modal/popUp page with several tab on it.
You can look at this pict --> [Image](http://nanonimos.com/tabs.jpg)

I've ask in Ionic Forum but still didnt get the proper answer or suitable with my case.

Here's my pen : `[http://codepen.io/harked/pen/ZGxGpb][2]`

Anyone can give the clue/advice?

It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In [$IonicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) you can specify `templateUrl` in `options` something like this

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    templateUrl: '....'
```

In the template create tabs and handle them with the controller. Good luck!